# wp responsive theme footer resize height

Tags: php, wordpress

html, and php.  I have added a footer img to the WP responsive them by using a child theme and altering the footer.php file. I can adjust the width but I can't seem to change the height.  Can any one help out with this?  Thank you.

Here is the php file:

`

```
// Exit if accessed directly
if( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/**
 * Footer Template
 *
 *
 * @file           footer.php
 * @package        Responsive
 * @author         Emil Uzelac
 * @copyright      2003 - 2014 CyberChimps
 * @license        license.txt
 * @version        Release: 1.2
 * @filesource     wp-content/themes/responsive/footer.php
 * @link           http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Footer_.28footer.php.29
 * @since          available since Release 1.0
 */

/*
 * Globalize Theme options
 */
global $responsive_options;
$responsive_options = responsive_get_options();
?>
<?php responsive_wrapper_bottom(); // after wrapper content hook ?>
</div><!-- end of #wrapper -->
<?php responsive_wrapper_end(); // after wrapper hook ?>
</div><!-- end of #container -->
<?php responsive_container_end(); // after container hook ?>

<div id="footer" class="clearfix">
    <?php responsive_footer_top(); ?>

    <div id="footer-wrapper">

        <?php get_sidebar( 'footer' ); ?>

        <div class="grid col-940">

            <div class="grid col-540">
                <?php if( has_nav_menu( 'footer-menu', 'responsive' ) ) { ?>
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                           'container'      => '',
                                           'fallback_cb'    => false,
                                           'menu_class'     => 'footer-menu',
                                           'theme_location' => 'footer-menu'
                                       )
                    );
                    ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <!-- end of col-540 -->

            <div class="grid col-380 fit">
                <?php echo responsive_get_social_icons() ?>
            </div>
            <!-- end of col-380 fit -->

        </div>
        <!-- end of col-940 -->
        <?php get_sidebar( 'colophon' ); ?>

        <div class="grid col-300 copyright">
            <?php esc_attr_e( '&copy;', 'responsive' ); ?> <?php _e( date( 'Y' ) ); ?><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
                <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- end of .copyright -->

        <div class="grid col-300 scroll-top"><a href="#scroll-top" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'scroll to top', 'responsive' ); ?>"><?php _e( '&uarr;', 'responsive' ); ?></a></div>

        <div class="grid col-300 fit powered">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( 'http://cyberchimps.com/responsive-theme/' ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Responsive Theme', 'responsive' ); ?>">
                Responsive Theme</a>
            <?php esc_attr_e( 'powered by', 'responsive' ); ?> <a href="<?php echo esc_url( 'http://wordpress.org/' ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'WordPress', 'responsive' ); ?>">
                WordPress</a>
        </div>
        <!-- end .powered -->

    </div>
    <!-- end #footer-wrapper -->

    <?php responsive_footer_bottom(); ?>
</div><!-- end #footer -->
<?php responsive_footer_after(); ?>





<img class="footer-image" src="/wp-content/themes/responsive-child/Image/bgtest.jpg"
alt="bgtest.jpg" width="990" height="50">




<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Might be overriden by CSS rules. Check the stylesheet.

Comment: Responsive styling is typically governed by CSS; would need to see stylesheet, or better yet, a live link, to help you diagnose.